# Nuxt 3 - setup Redis using runtime configuration

Tags: redis, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Using Nuxt 3.3.2 I have Redis integration implemented as shown in Nuxt 3 docs:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#example-using-redis

It works, only the connection is hard-coded in `nuxt.config.ts`. Is it possible to make it configurable using Nuxt runtime config variables?

I managed to this:

```
redis: {
  driver: 'redis',
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASS
}
```

but those are underlying system env variables, not the Nuxt ones. So it is an option, but not the ideal one.

I also tried `useRuntimeConfig()`, but got error it is undefined when used inside `nuxt.config.ts`

The question was originally asked at [Nuxt GitHub forum](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20195), but no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/unjs/nitro/issues/1161#issuecomment-1511444675) by one of the Nuxt collaborators.

The key is to define Nuxt server plugin in `server/plugins` directory:

```js
import redis from "unstorage/drivers/redis";

export default defineNitroPlugin(() => {
  const storage = useStorage();
  storage.mount(
    "/redis",
    redis({
      // useRuntimeConfig() is available here
    })
  );
});
```

According to the discussion, more convenient way might be implemented into Nuxt eventually. But so far this "workaround" gets the job done.